# DOS scripting - for MSFTP server

Tags: dos

I am starting an FTP session using:

> "C:\Program Files\FTP
>   Server\msftpsrvr.exe" -start

Now I want it to wait until it has find a file with a specified string.

Details:
I am using Mini core ftp on my server and Winscp on my client.
The client's time schedule keeps changing. I follow the following steps for automation:

On server

1. `msftpsrvr.exe -start`

On client:

1. `cd "C:\Program Files\WinSCP"`
2. `winscp.exe /console /script=script` to get backup and put file with status

No the server should read the status after copy is finished and then stop the ftp server.

How can I tell the server to pause untill that file is updated with "done" string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, the solution is very asynchronous.

Here is what I have done.

Started mftp server, after the backup finishes - it writes a flag to a file. The client side gets the file and reads the flag (polling every 30 min) and start copy.

It is not a good solution. but works for me

Comment: Why don't you post the solution so that people can see it?

Comment: the solution is very asynchronous. Here is what I have done. started mftp server, after the backup finishes- it writes a flag to a file. the client side gets the file and reads the flag (pooling every 30 min) and start copy. It is not a good solution. but works for me.

Comment: the comment is very repetitious :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PowerShell, welcome to the 21st century

Here is some nifty stuff to get you started:

- [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) includes an example

$0.02